# No permission to access file

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine

I'm creating game using the Unity game engine. In this game I grab a screenshot and save that to Unity's default folder ("Application.persistentDataPath"):

> /data/data/de.mytest.mygame/files/Screenshot.png

Now I would like to share this screenshot via Android. To do so I'm calling the corresponding java code from Unity.

This for example returns TRUE:

```
AndroidJavaObject fileObject = new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", imageFileName);
bool fileExist = fileObject.Call<bool>("exists");
Debug.Log("File exist : " + fileExist);
```

But when I try to create a sharing intent using android.content.Intent and putExtra to share this image, I get an Exception:

> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /data/data/de.mytest.mygame/files/Screenshot.png: open failed: EACCES
>   (Permission denied)

How can I fix this permission problem?

Edit:
The intent is created like this:

```
 AndroidJavaClass intentClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.content.Intent");
AndroidJavaObject intentObject = new AndroidJavaObject("android.content.Intent");

intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setAction", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("ACTION_SEND"));
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("setType", "image/*");
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_SUBJECT"), subject);
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TITLE"), title);
intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_TEXT"), message);

AndroidJavaClass uriClass = new AndroidJavaClass("android.net.Uri");
AndroidJavaObject fileObject = new AndroidJavaObject("java.io.File", imageFileName);
AndroidJavaObject uriObject = uriClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("fromFile", fileObject);

intentObject.Call<AndroidJavaObject>("putExtra", intentClass.GetStatic<string>("EXTRA_STREAM"), uriObject);
AndroidJavaClass unity = new AndroidJavaClass("com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer");
AndroidJavaObject currentActivity = unity.GetStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("currentActivity");
currentActivity.Call ("startActivity", intentObject);
```

Comment: Which permissions have you defined in your manifest.xml?

Comment: How are you building your intent exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You  might be missing one of the permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Hm, this could be it. But my Nexus 5 doesn't even have external storage. So what exactly does "external" mean here?

Comment: check file path and  check file available on that path because java.io.FileNotFoundException also occur

Comment: The file is there alright. But adding the permissions did not help :-(

Answer (score 0):

Files cannot be easily shared from the App folder because of security issues, and you cannot just share a File object across apps. The usual way is to implement a [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html) or just use the [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html). So what you share is the URI for the file, and the other app reads it from the provider.

But for that you will have to add some code with a Provider as an [Android plugin](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html) in your Unity project, and declare it in the manifest so that it can get invoked.

I think it might be easier (although not very clean) to save the file in the shared pictures folder using the methods of [Environment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(java.lang.String)):

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File file = new File(path, "Screenshot.png");
// write to that file
```

And later share the URI to the file using [Intent.EXTRA_STREAM](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_STREAM) as the extra key:

```
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
```